# If else statement for javascript click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two statements. What I am trying to do is when someone clicks on `#area_a` then hide then entire `#area_b` div **without** activating the `focusout` for the `#area_b_textbox`.  But I've tried different code (which I am not including here because it is incorrect and want to get your suggestions) and what is happening is it is activating the `focusout` everytime I click on the `#area_a` div.

JQuery base actions

```
$("#area_a").click(function() { $("#area_b").hide(); });

$("#area_b_textbox").focusout(function() {$("#area_b_error").show();});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="area_a"></div>

<div id="area_b">
  <input id="area_b_textbox">
  <div id="area_b_error"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Set focus back in the handler; best you can do-if you click on something, you're gonna lose focus from something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hack around the problem with a timer. Timers usually smell bad but I think it is your safest bet here. If you try using hover or other mouse events you might run into trouble with keyboard navigation and activation or the lack of "hoverish" events on touch interfaces (and we can't pretend those don't exist anymore).

Something like this:

```
var timer_kludge = {
    start: function(fn) {
        this.id = setTimeout(fn, 200);
    },
    stop: function() {
        if(this.id)
            clearTimeout(this.id);
        this.id = null;
    },
    id: null
};

$('#area_a').click(function() {
    timer_kludge.stop();
    $('#out').append('<p>click</p>');
});
$('#area_b_textbox').focusout(function() {
    timer_kludge.start(function() {
        $('#out').append('<p>textarea focusout</p>');
    });
});
$('#area_b_textbox').focusin(function() {
    timer_kludge.stop();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/s8kw8/1/

You'd want to play with the 200 timeout a bit to see what works best in your circumstances.

Comment: how about disabled people, they could use a long time to reach the button or what if area_a is on a totally different position on the site... i don't think this is a better solution.

Comment: @meo: The timer is started when the `<textarea>` loses focus so there is no problem, the `<textarea>` will have focus until they "click" the link (and then the `click` handler will be triggered before the timer runs out) or they "click" outside the textarea (and then it should activate the focusout handler).

Comment: @meo: Good call thinking about accessibility issues though, a lot of accessibility issues apply to touch (and text) based interfaces as well as interfaces for the disabled.

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible since you loose the focus automatically when you click somewhere else...

What you need to do is to unbind the focusout event on hover of the `#area_a` and rebind it later on...

```
$("#area_a").click(function() { 
   $("#area_b").hide()
}),hover(
  function(){
    $("#area_b_textbox").unbind("focusout")
  },
  function(){
    $("#area_b_textbox").focusout(function() {$("#area_b_error").show();});
  }
)
```

PS: what is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: Does that work? You'll already have lost focus on the click, no?

Comment: oh you are right. Need to think of something else. I have changed it to hover

Comment: they fire the hover event also.. Ever wondered why dropdown navigation system based on hover still work on the ipad or iphone? ;) But i see you point...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a flag to ignore next focusout (blur?) event.

```
ignoreNextFocus = false;
$("#area_a").click(function() { ignoreNextFocus=true; $("#area_b").hide(); });
$("#area_b_textbox").focusout(function() { if(!ignoreNextFocus)$("#area_b_error").show();ignoreNextFocus=false;});
```

On that note setting the flag on click event might be too late. If it is the case, try mousedown event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible since by definition the focus has to leave the #area_b_textbox if the user is going to click a button.